# Запрошенный URL / wp-admin / не найден на этом сервере

Tags: wordpress, apache, unix

Запрошенный URL / wp-admin / не найден на этом сервере.
Сервер Apache / 2.4.10 (Unix) на hi-news.site Порт 80
Почему пропал мой сайт `https://hi-news.site/wp-admin/`  и как его восстановить?

Comment: У вас даже сайт не залит..... Судя по главной странице

Comment: Зайдите в базу данных и там гляньте адрес или в корне сайта посмотрите как папка называется.